# How to use msilib.OpenDatabase() in python

Tags: python-2.7, windows-installer, registry

Im trying to use msi library to read some specifc informations in the database of msi file by using the function openDatabase
My code is:

```
db = msilib.OpenDatabase(msiFile, MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)
view = db.OpenView("SELECT Key, Name, Value FROM Registry")

while True:
 view.Execute(None)
 record = view.Fetch()
```

But I got an error:
NameError: global name 'MSIDBOPEN_READONLY' is not defined

Comment: Try `db = msilib.OpenDatabase(msiFile, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)`

Comment: I tried it but I got another error:  _msi.MSIError: unknown error 6e

Comment: 6e = 110. Per `net helpmsg 110` this means: *The system cannot open the device or file specified.*

Comment: Thank you for help, but now i 've new problem, when i use fetch i have an error                                                 
    record = view.Fetch()
    <class '_msi.MSIError'> unknown error 103